# Failed to properly display some elements

Tags: html, css

When I used snipped it didn't quite show it as it is in reality but the idea is that i try to make a div to display something like this..but I failed. I mention that I need to put that image into a div because I take it using php to switch between a red arrow pointed down and this one. But in order to put it into snippet I used a online source. The problem is that I cannot even dispay the dotted line (.target) between them.

[image]

```css
.target {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-right: 2px dotted black; 
  color: black;
  height: 50px;
  width: 3px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row" style="margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; height: 100%;">
  <div class="col-sm-6" style="width:50%;">
    <div class="stats-item" style="width:40%;">
      <h1>0</h1>
      <p>Clicks</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="target"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-6" style="width:50%;">
    <div class="stats-item" style="width:40%;">
      <div class="image" style="width: 30px;">
        <img src="https://app.klipfolio.com/images/resources/indicators/hd/ind-triangle-up-green.png" />
      </div>
      <p>vs 0 prev. 7 days</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You aren't giving `. target` a height so of course it isn't visible.

Comment: I did..now it is displayed correctly but still I can't figure out how to make everything work

Answer (score 0):

The `.target` takes up space between columns so they won't stay next to each other. You need to set `position: absolute` for it to take it out of the grid flow. Then position it accordingly. (Mind that inside this snippet the effect won't be visible because the available space is so limited that the default `col-xs-12` class won't take over `col-sm-6` for columns.

```css
.target {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-right: 2px dotted black; 
    color: black;
    height: 50px;
    width: 3px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row" style="margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; height: 100%;">
  <div class="col-sm-6" style="width:50%;">
    <div class="stats-item" style="width:40%;">
      <h1>0</h1>
      <p>Clicks</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="target"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-6" style="width:50%;">
    <div class="stats-item" style="width:40%;">
      <div class="image" style="width: 30px;">
        <img src="https://app.klipfolio.com/images/resources/indicators/hd/ind-triangle-up-green.png" />
      </div>
      <p>vs 0 prev. 7 days</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Make another column for div.target.**

```
<div class="row" style="margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; height: 100%;">
  <div class="col-sm-2" >
    <div class="stats-item" style="width:40%;">
      <h1>0</h1>
      <p>Clicks</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-1">
  <div class="target"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-2" >
    <div class="stats-item" >
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://app.klipfolio.com/images/resources/indicators/hd/ind-triangle-up-green.png" />
      </div>
      <p>vs 0 prev. 7 days</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**And Your CSS**

```
.target {
  border-right: 2px dotted black; 
  color: black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 1px;
}
```

See Here Example :  http://codepen.io/ihemant360/pen/wWgoMW